# invocation order of overloaded methods in JAVA

Tags: java, int, literals, overloading

I'm studying some exams of java and I came across with this question:

```
//Write the output of this program:

public static void method(Integer i) { System.out.println("Integer"); }
public static void method(short i) { System.out.println("short"); }
public static void method(long i) { System.out.println("long"); }
//...
public static void main(String []args) {
method(10);
}

//ANSWER: long
```

The explanation describes that for an integer literal, the JVM matches in the order: int, long, Integer. Since there is no method with int type parameter, then looks for long type; and so on.

In this explanation they only provide the order for int, long and Integer.
so my question is: What is the complete order list when an integer literal is introduced in a method that is overloaded for every type (that uses integers)?

Also, what is the order for float, double etc...?(decimal values)

Comment: Here it is - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete list might be  int, long, float, double, Integer, Number/Comparable/Serializable, Object.

Note: the Number, Comparable, and Serializable are ambiguous. An explicit cast would be needed to pick one of them.

Comment: It doesn't took  more than 1 sec after finishing my question when I got an answer lol, THANKS!

Comment: @HugoMedina Took me 4 mins to check it. ;)

Comment: what about the 'short' type?

Comment: @HugoMedina An `int` will not be implicitly narrowed to a `short`. (Ignoring assignment operators which allow all sorts of strange things)